# R - Getting "Error "..." does not exist in current working directory, but it's clearly there

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to write a loop in R. The first part of my code works fine, which is to concatenate a URL and a value containing three years (1999-2001).

```
url <- 'https://www.baseball-almanac.com/players/baseball_births.php?order=LastName,%20FirstName&y='
birth_yrs <- as.character(1999:2001)

for(i in birth_yrs) { 
  nam <- paste("year", i, sep = ".")
  assign(nam, i)
  nam2<-paste(url, i ,sep = "")
  assign(nam,paste(url, i ,sep = ""))
}
```

This gives me the following values in my Global Environment:

[View of my Global Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6pCC.png)
What I would like to do now is to use the read_html() function in the from the xml2 package in a loop to save the html page. My code is the following:

```
for(i in birth_yrs) { 
  nam3 <- paste("baseball", i, sep = ".")
  assign(nam3,read_html(paste("year",i,sep = "")))
}
```

Running this code gives me the following error message:

*Error: 'year1999' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/.....').*

When I run the code:

```
test<-read_html(year.1999)
```

It works perfect with no issues:
[The file code worked fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AYeI.png)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `year.1999` is a dataframe existing in the environment, "year.1999" is a filename which doesn't seem to exist in the working directory.

Comment: In general I strongly advice you avoid the use of `assign` and `get`. They make code much harder to read and cause confusion like this. It's much easier to use more basic data structures like named list. Note there is a big difference between `read_html(year.1999)` and `read_html("year.1999")` and when you are using `paste()` you are essentially creating a string value so `read_html(paste("year.1999"))` is like the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Waldi you are providing a test string. If you would like to use the content of a variable when only supplying a test string you can use `get()`. When you provide get a string, it will search for a variable name that matches the provided string, and return the content stroed in the matching variable. Try:

```
    for(i in birth_yrs){ 
  nam3 <- paste("baseball", i, sep = ".")
  assign(nam3, read_html( get(paste("year",i,sep = ".") ) ))
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the data in list. You can use `lapply` to extract whatever value you want from each.

```
library(rvest)
url <- paste0('https://www.baseball-almanac.com/players/baseball_births.php?order=LastName,%20FirstName&y=', 1999:2001)
url_data <- lapply(url, read_html)
```